# Easy-thumbnails not generated for images with uppercase extensions

Tags: django, easy-thumbnails

I am using the latest version of easy-thumbnails and it is working great except that when a user tries to upload an image with an uppercase extension e.g. image.JPG, no thumbnail gets generated. I have confirmed that my simply changing the JPG to jpg, all works well. How can I get this fixed please?

**Update**

As a temporary workaround, I have written a rename function on the model changing the extention to lowercase.

Comment: Are you using Django's filebrowser?

Comment: No, the client's file browser is used

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to put this line on your project's `settings.py` file:

```
THUMBNAIL_PRESERVE_EXTENSIONS = None
```

Tell me if it works like this, maybe this forces the module to process that kind of image.

However, it's not very common to have such uppercase extensions.

Comment: That setting is the default, but I tried it none the less. Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: What type of field are you using: ThumbnailerField, FileField or ImageField?